# Android Studio : variable values not showing in debug

Tags: android

I would like to debug an app, but when I start debugging, I can't see any variable values :

[image: Image_variable.png]

I'm using the last version of Android studio on Windows 8.1 and debugging on an Android Virtual Machine Nexus 5X.

Comment: Did you set any breakpoints?

Comment: yes i did, i also tried without setting breakpoints

Comment: Android Studio > Preferences > Debugger > Android Debug Bridge (ADB) enable “Use libusb backend”